# Validate an address field with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to validate a street address using javascript. The address must be adhere to a `Address 12` like format where it begins with one or more characters, followed by a space and then followed by at least one digit.

I'm using the following regexp:

```
(/[a-zA-Z+\s?\d+$]/.test(field)
```

and various modifications of these, but is not working well. How can i re-write to be correct?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are using `[]` which denotes character class. Only one out of many characters defined in it will be matched. In your case it's matching only `A`. You will have to use `\w+ \d+` which means `Any number of characters` `space` `one or more digits`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing bracketed character sets with other regex commands, such as optional and repeating. Something like this would match a word followed by a space by a number:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+\s[0-9]+$/.test(field_value)
```

That said, I don't know any address format that has a single word followed by a number, without allowing for, for example, multiple words in the street name. Which could be achieved like this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+\s)+[0-9]+$/
```

Comment: Additionally, if the space really is optional (which your first attempt at the regex would suggest), you can add a `?` after it: `[a-zA-Z]+\s?[0-9]+`

Comment: Thanks a lot @NickWhite. Your answer is what i needed!

Comment: Wasn't the requirement for only one space ? `\s` adds tabs too. Might wanna edit your answer.

Comment: Additionally you can use `\w` and `\d` instead of `[A-Za-z]` and `[0-9]`.

Comment: \t is a tab character. \s is a whitespace character.
 That `/^([a-zA-Z]+\s)+[0-9]+$/` was exactly what i needed

Comment: @ParisL: For your information `\s` means `space`, `\t - tab`, `\r - carriage return`, `\n - newline.` All in one

Answer (score 0):

You are using `[]` which denotes character class. Only one out of many characters defined in it will be matched.

In your case it's matching only A.

You will have to use `/\w+ \d+/` which means `Any number of characters` `space` `one or more digits`

**<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zH0wH8/1)</kbd>**